# Texts, which should appear over images on hover, appears only over one image

Tags: html, css

Problem described in title.

I've posted my code here, it's without the images but I hope you understand the problem anyway. 
I think it's something with positioning (absolute/relative), but changing positioning of .figure to relative hides that section from my webpage.
[Video](https://app.box.com/s/j17rqumnd141qz861gl5wlilrjg2wom6), which allow you to understand problem (quickly recorded via phone)

https://jsfiddle.net/p0txnbbx/3/

```
    .section-meals {
        padding: 0;  
    }

    .meals-showcase {
        list-style: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .meals-showcase li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }

    .meal-photo {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .meal-photo img {
       /* opacity: 0.7;*/
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
     -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
     -moz-transition: all 300ms;
     transition: all 300ms;
        /*-webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
        transform: scale(1.15);
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
        transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
        transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
        transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;*/
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .meals-showcase li:hover img {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
     transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .meals-showcase figcaption {
     /*background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);*/
     color: white;
     display: table;
     height: 100%;
     left: 0;
     opacity: 0;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
     -moz-transition: all 300ms;
     transition: all 300ms;
     -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
     -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
     transition-delay: 100ms;
     z-index: 100;
    }

    .meals-showcase figcaption p {
     display: table-cell;
     font-size: 1.5em;
     position: relative;
      color: #000;
        left: 20px;
     top: -40px;
     width: 289px;
     -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .meals-showcase li:hover figcaption p {
     -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
     -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
     transform: translateY(100px);
    }

    .meals-showcase li:hover figcaption {
     opacity: 1;
    }
    <section class="section-meals">
                <ul class="meals-showcase clearfix">
                    <li>
                        <figure class="meal-photo">
                            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption><p>Korean bibimbap</p></figcaption>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure class="meal-photo">
                            <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Simple italian pizza with cherry tomatoes">
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption><p>Korean bibimbap</p></figcaption>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure class="meal-photo">
                            <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Chicken breast steak with vegetables">
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption><p>Korean bibimbap</p></figcaption>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure class="meal-photo">
                            <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="Autumn pumpkin soup">
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption><p>Korean bibimbap</p></figcaption>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="meals-showcase clearfix">
                    <li>
                        <figure class="meal-photo">
                            <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="Paleo beef steak with vegetables">
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption><p>Korean bibimbap</p></figcaption>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure class="meal-photo">
                            <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="Healthy baguette with egg and vegetables">
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption><p>Korean bibimbap</p></figcaption>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure class="meal-photo">
                            <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="Burger with cheddar and bacon">
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption><p>Korean bibimbap</p></figcaption>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure class="meal-photo">
                            <img src="img/8.jpg" alt="Granola with cherries and strawberries">
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption><p>Korean bibimbap</p></figcaption>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
```

Comment: Can u add ur code in jsfiddle or plunker properly

Comment: Added it main post

Comment: Please try to add placeholder images to your jsfiddle. right now the texts just appear somewhere else, doesn't look like in the video. https://placehold.it/